# Downloading PDF in Selenium 4 Firefox opens a new tab

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to change the version of a Selenium Project from 3 to 4. The issue that I am facing is that after downloading a PDF using Firefox, the PDF is opened in a new tab, and I do not wish for this.
I have set the capabilities that were supposed to handle this, but it still does not work.
The language is Java, I am using Selenium 4.12.0, firefox version is 116.

```
Firefox ffop = new FirefoxOptions();
ffop.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
ffop.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
ffop.addPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);
ffop.addPreference("useAutomationExtension", false);
ffop.addPreference( "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", false);
ffop.addPreference("pdfjs.firstRun", false);
ffop.addPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml");
ffop.addPreference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0");
ffop.addPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all", false);
```

I am passing the options as this:

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
static Map<String, Object> capabilities = new HashMap<>();
capabilities.put("moz:firefoxOptions", ffop);
firefoxOptions.setCapability("cloud:options",capabilities);

remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, firefoxOptions);
```

Any help is welcome.
Thank you.